# Firefox flickering when removing element from DOM at the end of animation, while in Chrome it works fine

Tags: javascript, firefox, animation

I've created a page transition via Javascript routing & the Web Animation API. It loads the new page and then gradually animates from the old page towards the new page. At the end of this cycle, I remove the content of the old page. But the removing doesn't seem to work correctly in Firefox, because it flickers the old content for just a moment, which makes it pretty ugly. Chrome does just fine.

The demo can be found here: http://daan.onl/dev/js/page-transition/index.html.

What causes this difference and how can I fix it?

Comment: try `fadeOut.onfinish =` ... instead of `fadeIn.onfinish =` - which makes more sense as you are removing the "fadeOut" content when the "fadeOut" animation ends

Comment: as a bonus - you don't need to `return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      resolve(cache[url]);
    });` - just `return cache[url];`

Comment: @JaromandaX Hmm, I implemented the solution `fadeOut.onfinish =`, but it doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.. it stays the same. Still the flickering on `oldContent.parentNode.removeChild(oldContent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your timing to

```
var timing = {
  duration: 1500,
  iterations: 1,
  fill:'both'
}
```

at least for the oldContent

This will ensure that the transform style is not removed at the end of the animation